Why does Rust allow multiple mutable borrows of struct fields but not array elements?
I am new to Rust (Moving from C++) and I cannot seem to wrap my head around the Rust's compile time borrowchecker for this specific case:
Using a struct
When I create a struct and mutably borrow references of the two fields within the same scope, the code is compiled and the expected output is given:
struct Node2{
    value: i32,
    value2: i32,
}


fn main() {
    let mut node = Node2{value: 10, value2: 10};
    let a = &mut node.value2;
    let b = &mut node.value;

    *a = 5;
    *b = 4;

    println!("a: {}, b: {}", a, b);

prints: a: 5, b: 4
Using an array
If I try to do the same thing with arrays, this doesn't work anymore and the borrow checker will throw me an error.
Comming from C++, this seems counter intuitive to me, because structs are allocated as contiguous memory (Same as Arrays / vectors) and the fields are accessed as offsets (Exactly same as arrays), so there is no overall difference in the way the data is accessed---It is basically just a different view to the same data.
Here is the code:
    let mut item_vector = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let av = &mut item_vector[0];
    let bv = &mut item_vector[1];

    *av = 10;
    *bv = 20;

    println!("av: {}, bv: {}", av, bv);


and it fails with the following error:

   |
24 |     let av = &mut item_vector[0];
   |                   ----------- first mutable borrow occurs here
25 |     let bv = &mut item_vector[1];
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
26 |
27 |     *av = 10;
   |     -------- first borrow later used here

Reason for the confusion
I understand that mut is supposed to be an exclusive write access, but I don't understand why it is different for structs / arrays.
Surely any condition racing that a struct is vulnerable to, would make an array vulnerable in the same way.
With my limited knowedlge, it seems inconsistent.
I would appreciate a run down of why this is happeing and what was the design decision behind this, (Why does borrowing a single element from an array count as if the whole array was borrowed by the checker and why does the same not apply for a struct)

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get_many_mut (unstable)

The Splitting Borrows section of the Rustonomicon addresses this very question.
